# customizing xsl-fo page-sequences in ditac

Tags: xsl-fo, dita, page-setup

I understand how to make modifications to the ditac stock xsl-fo stylesheets by importing them, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to assign a different page-sequence than the stock page-sequence that is being used, or how to assign a custom page sequence that I created. For example, I have a cover_page.dita that I would like to use as the title page, but it is being assigned the chapter page sequence and it follows the table of contents. I'm also not sure how to customize the title page, because as of now it only displays the title. Also, I don't know how to change the order of the pages in the PDF:

Currently:

1. stock title page
2. stock toc
3. cover_page.dita

I would like to change it to:

1. cover_page.dita, if it exists, otherwise use title page
2. toc

This is my cover_page.dita:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">
<topic outputclass="cover" id="cover" xml:lang="en">
      <title>Spare Parts List</title>
      <body>
            <image href="../shared/media/cover_image.jpg" />
            <div outputclass="contact-information">
                  <div outputclass="address">
                        <p>ALPLA-AME Alwin</p>
                        <p>Mockenstrasse 34</p>
                        <p>6971 Hard / Austria</p>
                  </div>
                  <p>T: +53(0)2234/902-0</p>
            </div>
      </body>
</topic>
```

This is my ditamap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE bookmap 
    PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA 1.3 BookMap//EN" "bookmap.dtd">
<bookmap id="DMJPCP1928" 
    xml:lang="en"
    xmlns:ditaarch="http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/" 
    ditaarch:DITAArchVersion="1.3">
    
    <booktitle>
        <mainbooktitle>Cleaning</mainbooktitle>
    </booktitle>
    <chapter format="dita" href="cover_page.dita" navtitle="Cover Page" type="topic" />
    <chapter format="ditamap" href="front_matter.ditamap" navtitle="Front Matter" type="map" />
    <chapter format="ditamap" href="general.ditamap" navtitle="General" type="map"/>
    <chapter format="dita" href="machine_overview.dita" navtitle="Machine overview" type="topic"/>
    <chapter format="ditamap" href="515871.ditamap" navtitle="complete" type="map" />
    <chapter format="ditamap" href="515255.ditamap" navtitle="preparation" type="map" />
    <chapter format="ditamap" href="back_matter.ditamap" navtitle="Back Matter" type="map" />
</bookmap>
```

I tried to do something like this, but I'm getting the standard title page:

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class,' topic/topic ')][@outputclass='cover']">
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="title">
      
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" xsl:use-attribute-sets="base-style">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:call-template name="build-cover-footer"/>
        
      </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
  </xsl:template>
```

I appreciate any suggestions, thank you.